# Intimating reader process about termination of writer process in shared memory model

Tags: c++, linux, ipc, shared-memory, mmap

I have 2 processes communicating using shared memory(mmap). My requirement is that in case writer process is stopped(by kill/crash/connection down), then it should inform reader process somehow. I thought of adding one field in shared memory that will indicate if writer is alive. I can use sandbox mechanism to handle crash scenario and update that field. My question is, is there any better mechanism than this? Both the processes are written using C++.

Update :-

1. Two process are unrelated (No parent-child) relation.

Comment: If the two threads are a parent and child relationship, it's easy to use pipes. For other cases, we can consider network RPC through UNIX domain sockets and combine with heartbeats.

Comment: When the writer goes away, do you want the reader to immediately run new code, such as in a signal handler or new thread, or do you just want the reader to be able to check whether the writer is still there at certain points in its execution?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, I just want the reader to be able to check whether the writer is still alive before using contents of the shared memory.

Comment: anyone has any solution in mind?